# exclude category from wordpress if not required

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having a bad time trying to make wordpress querys excluding categories unless asked.

I mean, if not specifically asked (ex: $args= array('cat'=>'-35')) , the loop excludes this category.

what I got so far:

```
function exclude_categories( $wp_query ) {
    $excluded_cats = array( '-35' , '-36' );
    set_query_var( 'category__not_in', $excluded );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_categories' );
```

This is doing ok excluding posts with this category but then if I try to ask for posts with this category it wont display any.

Any sugestions?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the whole code with when you ask for posts including this category?

Basically, you can set these parameters to inlucde or exclude categories in the query.

```
    'category__not_in'=> array(1,2),
    'category__in' => array(3,3)
```

However in your example you have already pre-set `set_query_var( 'category__not_in', $excluded );`
categories so even if you use category__in the query won't use it because of the usage of `category__not_in`. You need to set this parameter to empty value.